# How to compile a folder with multiple files JS format, node_modules, package.json to an executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, package, nexe

Good evening, I would like to know if there's a way to compile what I asked in the title to an executable. I've tried in the past using the node library /nexe with success, but the exe would work only inside the root folder with all its components. If you try to run it outside the folder it won't work. I've tried pkg but without success as it would crash when opening. I've tried Dino but same result. If there's something I'm missing let me know.

The root folder structure is pretty simple and contains the following.

- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- folder with JS files that are connected to main.js
- main.js

Comment: What exactly is the program? A server? An app? What is it built with?

Comment: Hi, is an app built with nodejs and javascript. Is a simple terminal program that follow simple commands.